# How to remove brackets from JSON?

Tags: json, groovy

I have a groovy script that I want to return userDefinedErrorText. The issue I am having is that when parse my JSON I am having my failedForm variable equal [Failed] instead of "Failed".

If I remove the first pair of [] from my JSON input, I get the correct "Failed".

Is there a way to remove [] from the input JSON?

My Groovy

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText( aInputJson )

failedForm = json?.userDefinedErrorText
    
    if( failedForm == "Failed" ) {
        resultMessage = "false"
    }
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "step": "abcd",
    "message": {
      "ServiceRequest: abc": {
        "App Stack Form Exception": {
          "Expecting Form": "P",
          "Resulting Form": "P"
        },
        "JAS Response": {
          "fs_P": {
            "title": "I",
            "data": {},
            "errors": [
              {
                "CODE": "799L",
                "TITLE": "Error: Invalid Long Address Number",
                "ERRORCONTROL": "15",
                "DESC": "CAUSE . . . . The long address number entered is not found in the Address Book\\u000a               Master file (F0101).\\u000aRESOLUTION. .  Enter a valid long address number.",
                "MOBILE": "The long address number entered is not found in the Address Book\\u000a               Master file (F0101)."
              }
            ],
            "warnings": []
          },
          "stackId": 12,
          "stateId": 5,
          "rid": "8f4",
          "currentApp": "P",
          "timeStamp": "2022-04-22:11.25.03",
          "sysErrors": []
        }
      }
    },
    "timeStamp": "2022-04-22T11:25:03.235-0400",
    "userDefinedErrorText": "Failed"
  }
]
```

Comment: "If I remove the first pair of [] from my JSON input, I get the correct "Failed"." - If you remove the outer brackets I think you are changing the type from array to object. Is that your intent?  If yes, be aware that I think that is only going to work if the array you start with only contains 1 object.  Is that correct?

Comment: I am trying to make the JSON and object instead of an array. I'm not sure if I will always get just 1 object. Is there a better way to find this? My goal is to get failedForm = "Failed" instead of failedForm = [Failed]

Comment: Yes, there is a better way.  I have written a sample app to show you how to do it and I can share that but the JSON you pasted above is malformed and can't be parsed (for example: `"ServiceRequest: "abc": {`).  Can you fix that?  If you will post a valid JSON document that you want to parse, I can show you how to do that.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have corrected the JSON now. I'd love to see the example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue I am having is that when parse my JSON I am having my
> failedForm variable equal [Failed] instead of "Failed".

The following should work:

```
String jsonString = '''
[
  {
    "step": "abcd",
    "message": {
      "ServiceRequest: abc": {
        "App Stack Form Exception": {
          "Expecting Form": "P",
          "Resulting Form": "P"
        },
        "JAS Response": {
          "fs_P": {
            "title": "I",
            "data": {},
            "errors": [
              {
                "CODE": "799L",
                "TITLE": "Error: Invalid Long Address Number",
                "ERRORCONTROL": "15",
                "DESC": "CAUSE . . . . The long address number entered is not found in the Address Book\\\\u000a               Master file (F0101).\\\\u000aRESOLUTION. .  Enter a valid long address number.",
                "MOBILE": "The long address number entered is not found in the Address Book\\\\u000a               Master file (F0101)."
              }
            ],
            "warnings": []
          },
          "stackId": 12,
          "stateId": 5,
          "rid": "8f4",
          "currentApp": "P",
          "timeStamp": "2022-04-22:11.25.03",
          "sysErrors": []
        }
      }
    },
    "timeStamp": "2022-04-22T11:25:03.235-0400",
    "userDefinedErrorText": "Failed"
  }
]'''
    

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
String value = json[0].userDefinedErrorText

assert value == 'Failed'
```